# Eclipse RCP: Add project to CNF-based Navigator

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, cnf

I am working on an RCP application.  Currently, I am stuck on trying to get the project created from my custom wizard to open the files in my CNF-based navigator.  I am not really sure whether it needs to be done on the navigator-side or the wizard-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a couple tutorials that put me on the right path.  It turns out I needed a model for the project hierarchy and label/content providers.

http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-2-creating-a-custom-project-in-eclipse-adding-to-the-new-project-wizard/

http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-4-create-a-custom-project-in-eclipse-new-project-wizard-the-behavior/

http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-7-creating-a-custom-navigator/